# Trying to merge 10 rows using loops until lastrow, similarly for 8 columns in a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use loop for merging 10 cells which will have same data in column `A`:

`A2` to `A11` will have `L001-AIG Life & Retirement10002-0001-US GAAP--`

`A12` to `A21` Will have `0248-Parent & Other-2000002-0002-US GAAP--`

like this we will have data until 1000's of line which i need to merge manually to prepare a final report but i am not getting it to use loop for merging cells like 'A2-A11', 'A12-A21' to Until lastrow based on Column 'G' which no need to merge

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert()
Dim i As Long
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With Ws
Dim MyLastRow As Long
MyLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

'Loop through range backwards and merge

For i = 2 To MyLastRow 

    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(10, 0)).Merge

Next i

End With
End Sub
```

Similar to this we have to merge 10 rows same data from Column B, C, D E, F, J, K & L along with Column A.

I am trying it from last few days online everywhere but not got anything matching to my requirement, would be of great help if any one can help me out with this..

Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Have a great weekend !

Regards
Suresh

Comment: For i = i? And in your loop you don't use "i"?

Comment: "For i = 0" would be better :-)

Comment: Sorry I didn't type here correctly I used For i =2 to mylastrow

Comment: But where are you using "i"? It should be in your line which starts with "Range"

Comment: Yes I didn't use it at all that's why not moving ahead will try now n updAte For i =1 n by adding i in range thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

**EDIT** Updated per OP request with new requirement:

> Similary i wanted to use this for other 7 seven columns (B-F & J-L)
>   Can this be edited to adjust all columns in single code?

```
Sub Insert()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ColumnCell As Range
    Dim rIndex As Long
    Dim sColumns As String

    sColumns = "A:F,J:L"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For rIndex = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row Step 10
        For Each ColumnCell In Intersect(ws.Rows(1), ws.Range(sColumns)).Cells
            ws.Cells(rIndex, ColumnCell.Column).Resize(10).Merge
        Next ColumnCell
    Next rIndex
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot TIgeravatar :) Similary i wanted to use this for other 7 seven columns (B-F & J-L) Can this be edited to adjust all columns in single code?? if so that will be very short and super for me :)

Comment: @suresh7860 Updated answer

Comment: Thanks a ton Tigeravatar :) it solved my two days problem n now i can enjoy my weekend :) once again thanks a lot and have a great weekend expert :) Happy New Year too!!